# How to add a structure dump of a MySQL database to a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two data structure dumps that I generated from MySQL workbench. Now I would like to add them or include them in a PHP script and use them as variables:

```
var $sourceStruct = ''; //structure dump of the reference database
var $destStruct = ''; //structure dump of database to update
```

I am following this [script](https://www.phpclasses.org/package/4615-PHP-Compare-MySQL-databases-to-synchronize-structures.html) which compares two databases and synchronizes them but author did not give any explanation how to include the dumps in this script?

Comment: I followed the link to the PHP script and saw that there's a readme file https://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/23285.html linked to the project. Can't have access to it without creating an account. Doesn't it have a few information on how to use it?

Comment: @PatrickJanser it goes more into other details like which type of altering it supports and stuff like that but doesnt say anything about how to include .sql files...

Comment: @PatrickJanser I am actually now using `file_get_contents()` to read the .sql files into string but it seems like I cant use them inside a Class constructor : "Constant expression contains invalid operations
"

Comment: This error message can't help us a lot to know what's the error really. You may could try debugging your PHP code with *XDebug* and an IDE such as *Visual Studio Code*, *NetBeans* or *PhpStorm*. As we haven't got the code neither the dumps, it makes it quite difficult to help you undestand what's going wrong.

Comment: I got it to work but I had to do 2 corrections in the library, in `dbStruct.php`: first, the PHP opening tag `<?` should be replaced by `<?php`, the second correction was the class constructor function which should be renamed to `function __construct()`. This project seems quite old, but it worked with the `left_1.sql` and `right_1.sql` files. I took this library: https://packagist.org/packages/eliasfarah/db-struct-sync

Comment: @PatrickJanser thanks for your efforts! I tried your suggestions but could not make it work, can you please send a working copy of it so I can see it?

Comment: I updated my answer with all the process and explanations. I think I can't do better ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Usage:

```
var $sourceStruct = 'CREATE TABLE ...'; //add structure dump of the reference database here
var $destStruct = 'CREATE TABLE ...'; //add structure dump of database to update

$updater = new dbStructUpdater();
$updates = $updater->getUpdates($sourceStruct, $destStruct);
```

Result:

```
$updates == array (
    [0]=>"ALTER TABLE `b` MODIFY `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL",
    ...
)
```

Comment: you literally just copied something from the documentation and thats it. What you copied has nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: the question was how to use the dumps with this script. whats wrong with my answer?

Comment: where are the dumps in your answer? They are just empty variables

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you just want to get the dumps into the variables then read the files with PHP's built-in `file_get_contents()` function like this:

```php
var $sourceStruct = file_get_contents('source_dump.sql') or die('Could not read source SQL dump!');
var $destStruct = file_get_contents('destination_dump.sql') or die('Could not read destination SQL dump!');

$updater = new dbStructUpdater();
$updates = $updater->getUpdates($sourceStruct, $destStruct);

foreach ($updates as $update) {
  print $update . ';' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

This should generate all the SQL queries to update your destination database.

### My test with the lib

#### Alternative lib available with *Composer*

On my side, the problem was that I didn't get the library on *PHPClasses* because I didn't want to create an account. So I looked on Google to find this same library elsewhere and I got it available for installation with *Composer* at this place: https://packagist.org/packages/eliasfarah/db-struct-sync

I created a new folder and inside it I run this command:

```sh
composer require eliasfarah/db-struct-sync
```

This downloaded the project and created the following content:

- *composer.json*
- *composer.lock*
- vendor/

  - **autoload.php** <- the file to normally include.
  - composer/
  - eliasfarah/

    - db-struct-sync/

      - *composer.json*
      - **dbStruct.php** <- the file to correct.
      - nbproject/
      - tests/

        - *compareSql_1_left.sql*
        - *compareSql_1_right.sql*
        - **left_1.sql**
        - **right_1.sql**
        - *testCase.php*
        - *update_1.sql*
        - *viewClasses.sql*
        - *viewClassesSplit.php*

#### If you haven't got *Composer*

You could download the source code from GitHub: https://github.com/eliasfarah/dbStructSync

#### The edits on *dbStruct.php*

As it didn't work with my PHP 7 installation, I did some manual changes (not a good idea if we want to update the lib but it just was a test for your question). You could create a patch and add it to your own *composer.json* so that it's applied after installation.

1. The short opening tag at line 1 should be replaced by the long one: `<?` becomes `<?php`
2. At line 63, the class constructor should be renamed:

   ```php
   /**
    * Constructor
    * @access public
    */
    function dbStructUpdater()
    {
        $this->init();
    }
   ```

   becomes:

   ```php
   /**
    * Constructor
    * @access public
    */
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->init();
    }
   ```

#### My test's source code

I didn't have any MySQL dump so I used the ones provided by the tests in the library itself.

I wanted to use the *Composer*'s autoload file like we usually do but it didn't seem to work, probably because the lib is old and doesn't respect common conventions. So I directly included the PHP file like this:

```php
<?php

// Normal way to go not working :-(
//include 'vendor/autoload.php';

// Quick and dirty solution to have the class.
include 'vendor/eliasfarah/db-struct-sync/dbStruct.php';

$src = file_get_contents('vendor/eliasfarah/db-struct-sync/tests/left_1.sql');
$dest = file_get_contents('vendor/eliasfarah/db-struct-sync/tests/right_1.sql');

$updater = new dbStructUpdater();

$queries = $updater->getUpdates($src, $dest);

var_export($queries);
```

#### The output

```
array (
  0 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `cookyExpires` varchar(20) NOT NULL default \'30\'',
  1 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` ADD `cron_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL',
  2 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `enable_roles` tinyint(4) NOT NULL',
  3 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `group_table` varchar(255) NOT NULL default \'group\'',
  4 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `ldapswitch` tinyint(4) NOT NULL',
  5 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `masterPassword` varchar(32) NOT NULL',
  6 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `relations_table` varchar(255) NOT NULL default \'relations\'',
  7 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `std_group_tpl_none` varchar(255) NOT NULL',
  8 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `std_group_tpl_own` varchar(100) NOT NULL',
  9 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `std_group_tpl_sub` varchar(255) NOT NULL',
  10 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `stdCutOuts` varchar(255) NOT NULL',
  11 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `stdUserFields` varchar(255) NOT NULL',
  12 => 'ALTER TABLE `personalizer_config` MODIFY `user_table` varchar(255) NOT NULL default \'user\'',
)
```